# How do I assign rooms in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I designate rooms as bedrooms and assign them to specific dwarves?

Comment: Try this wiki page: http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Bedroom In general, for basic questions this the wiki is invaluable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>q</kbd>uery over the bed, press <kbd>r</kbd> to make the bedroom, size it with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>, then optionally <kbd>a</kbd>ssign the room to a dwarf, make it a <kbd>d</kbd>ormitory, or <kbd>n</kbd>ame the bed.

Comment: It's not always `alt`+`up`/`down`. For me it's `+` or `-`.

Comment: The instructions are, of course, dependent on the version; i gave what works for default; but i assume the user knows enough to know when he has non-default keybinds.